# Understand the structure "something to be"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

I found a sentence in the song Donna Donna that I am not sure to understand correctly.
It is "Stop complaining said the farmer, who told you a calf to be?".
I am not sure I understand correctly and how to retell or rephrase the question "who told you a calf to be?"
If I am asked to retell it into 2 or more sentences, how would I do?
Many thanks.

Comment: It just means "Who told you to be [born] a calf?" The order of the words has been changed to fit the metre and rhyme of the verse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Who told you a calf to be?"

Translates as:   "Who told you to be a calf?"

The "to be" is at the end of the sentence/phrase so that it can rhyme with "free".  Grammatically correct, but not a common way of speaking.

Comment: To native English speakers, it would be no problems. But to me, I am confused if I link the question in the song with any questions in English that have exactly the same form, for example "who gave you a nut to eat?"

Comment: I only half agree with @jim  I think this sentence is actually incorrect grammar. It is an ungrammatical reordering of a sentence to make a rhyme.  We can guess the meaning but that doesn't mean it follows any grammar that I'm aware of.  On the other hand, "Who gave you a nut to eat?"  is a completely grammatically correct question. It isn't analogous to "Who told you a calf to be?"  The big difference is that "gave" has two objects.

Comment: I was aware of the number of objects in my example but not very sure that "say" can take only one object and the grammar there.